# Cordova - cordova-uglify plugin changes content to 'undefined' when uglified

Tags: cordova, build, undefined, minify, uglifyjs

After installing,

```
npm install cordova-uglify --save-dev
```

and when running,

```
cordova build android --release
```

all the css are minified correctly.

But, JS files contents are replaced with 'undefined'.

What might be the issue?

What kind of information should I give you to solve it?

Please help guys?

**SOLUTION:**

Reinstall cordova-uglify with the version 0.2.9 (or) follow the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same behavior. Every js file contains only "undefined"

Comment: @koga73 Try with the post I provided in the answers section. Add comment in case this does not solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out we had an old uglify-config.json. Specifically this property was causing the output to be undefined:

```
"uglifyJsOptions": { "fromString": true }
```

More info on GitHub:
https://github.com/rossmartin/cordova-uglify/issues/35#issuecomment-344738718

Comment: Yeah. Seems it is fixed with the version 0.2.9 (from package.json -> "cordova-uglify": "^0.2.9"). I just now confirmed it with my mercurial changeset. Thanks for the link. :)

Answer (score 1):

Following this [post](http://blog.ionicframework.com/minifying-your-source-code/) for Minification and Uglification of Ionic 1 application helped me to solve the issue.

**Note:** Delete/Rename assets folder which is inside platforms/android, before building app. (It happens automatically when you build but do it manually just to make sure about it)

**EDIT 1:**
Reinstall cordova-uglify with the version 0.2.9.

Thanks.